# Extract range of elements from char array into string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, stdarray

I want to extract a range of elements from the beginning of a char array and put them into a string. The range may be less than or equal to the number of elements.

This is what I have come up with.

```
// buffer is a std::array<char, 128>

std::string message;

for (int i = 0; i < numberToExtract; ++i)
{
    message += buffer.at(i);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I've been looking at something like std::string's iterator constructor. E.g.  `std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end())` but I don't want all the elements.

Thanks.

Comment: When working with the STL, it's often a good idea to question for loops that initialize objects.

Comment: @Wolf [It's not the STL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5205571/2069064).

Comment: @Barry I [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library). I reword it to *watch out for C++ Standard containers initialized with for loops*.

Comment: @Wolf What do you mean?

Comment: I mean this pattern: `{1} container declaration (default construction) {2} for loop consisting in {3} append item to container`. Here `std::string` is the container: you want it *to contain* the extracted chars; done this way, you lose the option to make it const, because you have to declare it variable. I often look for alternatives of such undesirable side effects.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't have to go all the way to `end`:

```
std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + numberToExtract)
```

or:

```
std::string(&buffer[0], &buffer[numberToExtract]);
```

or use the constructor that takes a pointer and a length:

```
std::string(&buffer[0], numberToExtract);
std::string(buffer.data(), numberToExtract);
```

Comment: The constructor with ptr+len seems to be the most compact, +1, maybe this variant should go first.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

You're close with your second example, you can do

```
std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + numberToExtract)
```

This is using pointer arithmetic since array's use contiguous memory.

Answer (score 1):

Random access iterators let you do arithmetic operations:

```
std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + numberToExtract);
```